# The nested copy task of svnant can't work in gradle

Tags: gradle

i am a newbie of both gradle and groovy, now i am try to setup a tag on my subversion repository. Below is my gradle script:

```
task svnrev {
    // use ant to retrieve revision.
    ant.taskdef(resource: 'org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml') {
        classpath {
            fileset(dir: 'lib/DEV/svnant', includes: '*.jar')
        }
    }
    ant.svn(javahl: 'false', svnkit: 'true', username: "${_svn_user}", password: "${_svn_password}", failonerror: 'false') {
        ant.info(target: "${_svn_source_url}", propPrefix: 'svninfo')
    }
    // retrieve property of ant project and assign it to a task's property, refer to:
    // http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/can-t-find-or-extract-properties-from-svnant-info-function-in-gradle-td3335388.html
    ext.lastRev = ant.getProject().properties['svninfo.lastRev']
    // retrieve property of gradle project
    //getProject().properties['buildFile']
    }

task svntag << {
    ant.svn(javahl: 'false', svnkit: 'true', username: "${_svn_user}", password: "${_svn_password}", failonerror: 'false') {
        copy(srcurl: "${_svn_source_url}", desturl="${_svn_tag_url}", message="Create tag: ${_svn_tag_url}")
    }
}
```

The task 'svnrev' works normally, however when run 'gradle svntag', i constantly got a error message:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'AFM-IGPE-v2.0.0'.
> Could not find method copy() for arguments     [{srcurl=svn://192.168.2.9/IGPE/trunk_dev}, svn://192.168.2.9/IGPE/tag/AFM, Create tag: svn://192.168.2.9/IGPE/tag/AFM] on root project 'AFM-IGPE-v2.0.0'.
```

Also I tried

```
ant.copy(srcurl: "${_svn_source_url}", desturl="${_svn_tag_url}", message="Create tag: ${_svn_tag_url}")
```

And this time a different error message shown:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'AFM-IGPE-v2.0.0'.
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder.copy() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [[srcurl:svn://192.168.2.9/IGPE/trunk_dev], ...]
Possible solutions: any(), notify(), wait(), grep(), every(), find()
```

In fact I just simple translate my ant build.xml to gradle, and my ant build.xml works well. I have googled a period time, however no results found. Pls help and thanks in advance for your kindly help.

Comment: @ Ramon : why not accept the answer ? It will help you to get better help often.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I have no idea about 'accept' function before.

Comment: @ Ramon. Great!  Typically you accept answer that is most useful , upvote answers that was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight, I can spot two problems:

1. It has to be `task svnrev << {`, not `task svnrev {`.
2. Groovy named parameters are written with a `:`, not a `=`. (The latter instead assigns a default value to a positional parameter.) That's probably why you get the error for `ant.copy` (you mix and match between `:` and `=`).

Comment: What a foolish mistake i have made!! Thanks Perter, you are right, now replace = by :, it works!